# How do i connect to several websockets with different proxies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I need to be connected to multiple websockets at the same time. All connections must go through a proxy, which must be different for each websocket.

How can I connect to multiple websockets with different proxies without interrupting any of the connections? I want to use "websocket" library and W3CWebsocket.

Just tried only connecting to several websockets.

Comment: You could use [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware).  Create as many as you like.  But it's not clear from your question...where are you stuck?